# Import-Spweb is changing the user id if the user does not exist in the organisation anymore

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, stsadm, import

We had to restore a list (which has versionsing enabled) in our PROD enviornment SP 2010 August CU 2012. We used the following command metioned below:

```
Import-SPWeb http://example.com/projects/myList -path "E:\backups\myList\myList.cmp" -IncludeUserSecurity -UpdateVersions overwrite
```

The list was restored, however the users that did not exist in the organisation any longer were replaced with the user who performed the restore.

This is odd because we userd the correct flag as per the technet article [Import-SPWeb](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607613.aspx).
What's the point of having versioning if we loose the details?

Has anyone else faced this issue?

Comment: Was the -IncludeUserSecurity flag used during export?

Comment: Yes it was. We used CA unattach database restore a list option and include user security and all versions

Comment: Are unique permissions used for items in the list? The PowerShell command "Import-SPWeb" does not restore unique permissions even if the parameter "-IncludeUserSecurity" is used.

Answer (score 1):

If the user no longer exists the info about the user is lost during the restore.

It is very similar to this situation: you want to create new item and there is a lookup field. You can only select existing values. That is what happens during import - the items are "recreated" and when the user is not found the "dummy" value is added. In this case the username who runs the restore.

The flag IncludeUserSecurity is for user permissions, not to include non-existing users.

Try to check ShareGate tool specifications, they might be successful in solving this problem.